# Getting Exception when doing post call using Jersey Test framework

Tags: java, rest, post, jersey-2.0, jersey-test-framework

I am testing my rest all using jersey 2.x framework.
When doing my get calls everything works fine.
I am trying to test POST call but I getting exception when doing that call:

The Exception is:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()Z
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:264)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
at com.api.resources.v2x0.CategoryResourceTest.testPost(CategoryResourceTest.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: c

om.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType.isReferenceType()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:194)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:157)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1215)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1167)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:490)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:688)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:107)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1428)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:930)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:650)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:502)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
    ... 33 more
```

My Resource class looks like this:

```
@Path("/2/{subversion: [0-3]}/categories")
public class CategoryResource extends AbstractAuthenticationResource {
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CategoryResource.class);

//For now this property is deprecated. May be used in future.
private static String defaultCardinality = "10";

/**
 *
 * @param proxyCategory
 * @return Response Json Category response
 * @throws Exception
 */
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response createCategory(
        final Category proxyCategory) throws Exception {
    log.debug("Inside createCategory()");
}
}
```

And I am trying to make this call:

```
@Test
public void testPost() throws Exception {
    Category category = new Category("TestCategoryId","TestCategoryName");
    Response post = target("/2/0/categories").request().post(Entity.json(category));
    String s = post.readEntity(String.class);
}
```

And the Category class I am trying to pass looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Category")
public class Category implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8571194852191648098L;

protected String id;
protected String name;

public Category() {
}

public Category(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

And I am getting the above exception when making the post call.
I am using all latest version of jersey and jersey test.

**Update:**
These are my dependencies for this manner:

```
   <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>${junit.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you debug and check where it is breaking? `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: c` check the stack trace as reference. You could narrow down the problem area where code is breaking.

Comment: @pratikwebdev Yes, it is breaking when trying to call isReferenceType however when debugging I see that the JavaType object to have this function. Looks like a mix of version, however I am not sure where and why

Comment: You have some dependency version issues. Please show your dependencies.

Comment: @peeskillet I updated the post

Comment: Get rid of your Jackson dependencies. It's a different version from what `jersey-media-json-jackson` uses.

Comment: @peeskillet I can't, I am using them for my ObjectMapper

Comment: `jersey-media-json-jackson` pulls them in, but it uses a different version. Unless you specificly need version 2.7.0, then get rid of them, and just use the version the `jersey-media-json-jackson` pulls in.

Comment: If you need the latest version of Jackson, try adding [this one](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) and the one below it, in version 2.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jersey-media-json-jackson pulls them in, but it uses a different version. Unless you specificly need version 2.7.0, then get rid of them, and just use the version the jersey-media-json-jackson pulls in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you must remove dependencies relate to com.fasterxml.jackson and keep jackson on jersey dependencies. See attached my pom.xml  file. The solution was to comment Jackson com.fasterxml dependencies.

```
    <!-- JAX-RS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  <!-- Jersey -->       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-processing</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>  

<!-- Jackson          
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
-->
```